# Determining eigenvectors

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

So let us say we have the following matrix:

$$ A =
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & -3 \\
        1 & 5 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

I can calculate that the eigenvalues are $4$ and $2$.

So now it is needed to calculate $(4I-A)x = 0$ and $(2I-A)x = 0$ in order to get the eigenvectors. The first step is to turn it into an equationsystem which will thereafter be solved to determine the eigenvectors. But how do I go from the expression (for example $(4I-A)x = 0$) to the equationsystem?

Comment: Read through the following link for more details-http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/LA_Eigen.aspx.

Comment: If $B$ is a matrix and $x$ an unknown column vector, then $Bx=0$ _is_ a system of equation in the components of $x$. For instance with $B=(\begin{smallmatrix}1&3\\-1&-3\end{smallmatrix})$, the equation $B\binom xy=0$ is the system $x+3y=0$ and $-x-3y=0$.

Comment: Thank you Marc van Leeuwen, that cleared it all up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix-vector equation

$$\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}A\\B\end{bmatrix}$$

is equivalent to the equation

$$\begin{bmatrix}ax+by\\cx+dy\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}A\\B\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Thank you, I understand it now!

Answer (score 0):

1. Write out $4I-A$:
   $$
   4I-A=\begin{pmatrix}
   3 & 3\\
   -1 & -1
   \end{pmatrix}
   $$
2. Note that it is of rank one (that is, for example, second equation is a multiple of the first). What that means is that we can only restrict ourselves with finding $(x_1,x_2)$ such that $(3\,\,\,3)(x_1\,\,\,x_2)^T=0$.
3. The eigenvectors with some particular eigenvalue span a subspace. That means that if $x$ is an eigenvector of our matrix, then so is $\lambda{x}$. Thus, we can fix one of the coordinates (say, $x_1=1$) and plug it into our equation:
   $$
   3\cdot{1}+3x_2=0\\
   x_2=-1
   $$
   Here is our eigenvector:
   $$
   x=(1\,\,-1).
   $$